# Resolution keeps switching 1024x768

Tags: kubuntu

I am on Kubuntu. I change my resolution using xrandr and it works too. The only problem is if I sign out or reboot it goes back to 1024x768. Also I have to do the whole process of xrandr again and again... and again... every time I log back in. Any permanent solution?

I am new to Linux. Step by step guide would be appreciated.

Comment: You've not provided any release details; but changes made via `xrandr` take effect immediately (*if appropriate on your machine using Xorg*) but are not saved. If you make changes in your Kubuntu KDE Settings they're saved as permanent.   ie. Start -> Applications -> Settings -> System Settings then make change in *Display and Monitor* (*or however it appears in your unstated Kubuntu release*)